# How to get back to one navigation controller to another navigation controller from presentmodalview controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have used `PresentModalViewController`, I want to go back to another `viewcontroller` using back button, which having different navigation controller, so how to move from one `ViewController` to another which are on two different navigation controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the two were on the same navigation controller, you could use "unwind to controller", but since they are on two different view controllers, I think you'll have to do some sort of a hack :(

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 4, you can write, in the modal view controller that is presented,

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and this will dismiss the receiver and you'll be back at the original (non-modal) view controller.

Comment: he doesnt back to originalview he wants to anotherview...so how to go back to another viewcontroller when dismissmodelviewcontrlller..

Comment: @Kiranpatel This is getting more and more obscure. Can't he just present another one modally? Or push one to the navigation stack?

Answer (score 0):

for ModelView controller use this

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and for navigation controller

```
[self.navigationController popViewController:yourviewname animated:YES];
```